# Need some guides to make new kind of menu by Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I gonna make a new kind of menu by canvas. This is my first time i use canvas. So there several things i need your helps to start this kind of menu. Here is a images :

[image]

**sorry for this inconvenience. i edited this post and the only question is :**

**What is the principle to calculate radius of each area equally to draw like picture above if we have n flows ( in picture above is 3 flows) ?**

Please give me your suggestion or ideas about this kind of menu. I will appreciate. Thanks in advance for your consider, your idea ! Have a good day !

Comment: Please pick which question you want answered and post the code you've tried so far.  If you have multiple questions then ask multiple questions, don't pile them all into one.

Comment: To add to Robertc,show what research you've already done. People are more likely to help you when you're stuck than to do the work for you.

Comment: thanks robertc and jarrod, sorry for this, i edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius surely in the example above would be the length of the white lines, so any length you want??

If what you want is to equally divide the sector into n sub-sectors of equal arc length then you need to decide on what the maximum angle at the centre is going to be, in the above example its 90deg or pi/2 radians.

Ultimately, max angle, subsector arc length, subsector angle and radius are all connected through:

subsector_arc_length = radius * subsector_angle

subsector_angle = max_angle/n

or//
subsector_arc_length = radius * max_angle/n (Note these require radians)

But if your aim is draw this to canvas then something like:

```
var canvas = '<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 500px; background: lightblue;"></canvas>'
document.body.innerHTML += canvas;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var max_angle = Math.PI/2; //rad - 90deg
var no_of_flows = 10; 
var radius = 200; //pixels

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#333';
ctx.translate(250,350);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2);
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2 + max_angle/2);
for (var i=0; i<no_of_flows; i++) {
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, radius);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-1*max_angle/(no_of_flows-1));
};
```

Your main problem would you could probably generate a better image off canvas. + the event structure for the menu.